# How do I use a variable from one activity in another activity in Android?

Tags: java, android

We are trying to take in a room number (e.g. C123) from a user in one activity and use that variable in a different activity.
The other activity would look like:

```
roomNewNums.put("A100", "1")

...

roomNewNums.put("C303", "198")
```

We were using this to send over the variable from the second activity (first activity is irrelevant):

```
public static Bundle myNums = new Bundle();

SecondActivity.myNums.putString("newNumber", "destPos");
```

We used this to receive it in the third activity:

```
String newNum = SecondActivity.myNum.getString("newNumber");
```

What we think is the main error is the putString. It keeps saying

> Cannot resolve symbol 'putString'

We checked multiply websites and forums online and all were no help.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `shared memory` would be useful.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new class `MyApplication` extending `android.app.Application`
2. Create a static `Bundle` object in `MyApplication` class.

   ```
   public static Bundle mBundle = new Bundle():
   ```
3. Add `data` to `Bundle` using `key-value` pair from `SecondActivity`:

   ```
   MyApplication.mBundle.putString("newNumber", "destPos");
   ```
4. In `ThirdActivity`, Get `data` from `Bundle`:

   ```
   String newNum = MyApplication.mBundle.getString("newNumber");
   ```
5. Specify the `android:name` property in the `<application>` node in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <application 
       android:name=".MyApplication"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name">

       ................
       ....................
   </application>
   ```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of doing this

1) Use shared preference to store  room number in first activity and later fetch it from shared preference and use it .

2) Use singleton pattern to store data in model class and use it anymwhere in your app